# Marking down excel columns by the header names in xlwings/pandas

Tags: python, pandas, excel, xlwings

Is there a way I can mark down the Excel columns by the header names in any python webscraping tool?

For example, column A is snacks, B is drinks, and C is fruits:

[image: foods table]

In python, if I wanted to add grapes to the fruits table, I could do this:

```
wb.sheets['foods'].range('C5').value = "grapes"
```

However, if I add a new column in between the drinks and fruits called "vegetables", then the fruits would be in column D.

[image]

Now if I use the same code as before to add grapes to the fruit table, it would put it in the vegetables section:

```
wb.sheets['foods'].range('C5').value = "grapes"
```

I would therefore have to change the code so it becomes this:

```
wb.sheets['foods'].range('D5').value = "grapes"
```

Is there a way for python to know which column is which, so when I add columns in between I don't have to keep changing the code?

Comment: How do you determine that 'grapes' should go in the C column in the first place. And if its inserted once why would you need to insert 'grapes' again? So I mean are you programatically determinating at the start that 'grapes' are 'fruits' and that 'fruits' are column C or visually determinating that. Then you save that detail `wb.sheets['foods'].range('C5').value = "grapes"` why would you need to use it again and why would row 5 still be valid even if the column is?

Comment: im currently visually determining it, but is there a way I can programmatically determine it?

Comment: Sure, the simplest is your own list e.g `fruit_list = ['apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'grape']` then `if 'grape' in fruit_list` would return True. This method may be OK for your needs but obviously you need a List per category and the more categories and items per category the longer the lookup will take. Here there are 3 or 4 categories and you might check all to get a match for 'grape'. Also you would need to have every item you expect to enter in the appropriate List or the item will not be found.

Comment: Another option is you visually categorise the item the first time,  add the item to your sheet and also to the appropriate List so the next lookup you know will find the item. You could use a single Dictionary e.g. `cat_dict = {'grape': 'fruit', 'milk': 'd'...}` so look up grape in the Dict it returns 'fruit' for 'fruit', or look up 'milk' it returns 'd' for 'drink'. However If there are a great number of categories/items another method for look may work better including database or even web query.

Comment: The fruits and vegetables tables were just examples. I'm currently writing a really long code with pandas and xlwings, and whenever I add a column in my excel file, I keep having to change the whole code and shift all the columns one to the right. (e.g. E6 would become F6)

Comment: Actually it's hard to help knowing nothing about the background workflow. Maybe a good suggestion in this case would be to use [ListObjects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.ListObject), i.e. [Tables](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/overview-of-excel-tables-7ab0bb7d-3a9e-4b56-a3c9-6c94334e492c) (not Sheets). Please, elaborate the question to make your needs more obvious.

Comment: But why would you be keeping track of where your inserted a value? Once it's inserted, why insert it again? How do you know it was E6 the last time?

Comment: Im currently visually determining that it was in E6. Referring back to the grapes example, is it possible for the code to find the table that says "drinks" and then mark down its column letter? So that even if i add columns in between, the code would still be able to know which column is "drinks"

Comment: You can search Headers for the category then the column for the item

Answer (score 0):

#### Is it possible for the code to locate the header cell that says "drinks"?

Yes, it's possible in several ways. I believe one of the simplest would be to use [named ranges](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/define-and-use-names-in-formulas-4d0f13ac-53b7-422e-afd2-abd7ff379c64). Just create a named range *"drinks"* on the cell, where you put a string *"drinks"*. Then use `"drinks"` in place of an address to get the range with `"drinks"`. When you insert new columns, the named range's address will be adjusted automatically. Use [get_address](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/latest/api/range.html#xlwings.Range.get_address) to obtain the actual address of the range. Use methods [end](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/latest/api/range.html#xlwings.Range.end) and [offset](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/latest/api/range.html#xlwings.Range.offset) to locate the place to add a new item:

```py
headers = '''
   snacks
   drinks
   fruits
'''.strip().split()

ws = wb.sheets['foods']
for cell, header in zip(ws['1:1'], headers):
    cell.value = header
    cell.name = header    # be careful with spaces

data = '''
    chips,milk,apple
    fries,juice,orange
    candy,tea,banana
'''.strip().split()
data = [x.split(',') for x in data]
ws['A2'] = data

print(f'{ws['drinks'].get_address()=}')
ws['A:A'].insert()
print(f'{ws['drinks'].get_address()=}')

# add a new item to drinks
ws['drinks'].end('down').offset(1, 0).value = 'coffee'
```